# How to get the System properties from where Jenkins is accessed?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, devops

I have a server where Jenkins is configured and running as a service. My team is of 8 people who access the Jenkins via browser for performing deployments on demand.

How do get the System properties like the Username or the host name of the System where the Jenkins is accessed.

How do i configure the job so that i get to know who performed the deployment?

NOTE: I do not want to create users for all of them and provide credentials. There will be a unique credentials and everyone uses the same.

Regards

Kaushik

Comment: It's easy... you create accounts for everyone, or tie authentication to AD, leap, oauth, your choice, then use Jenkins history and logging to see who does what.  You either track people or you don't. What you are otherwise asking is just a bad idea. I hope the systems you are deploying do not follow similar security principles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no way around to create different Users or use @Ian w  suggestion.

If you stick to your idea to use only One credential  for all user you should consider setting a Parameter Choice for everyone  of your 8 People. So everyone pick his/her Name when he/she Starts a Job.

Take a looks at https://st-g.de/2016/12/parametrized-jenkins-pipelines

Comment: I should have just made my comment an answer, I guess! The risk with expecting a user to choose a parameter is the first is the default and you'll soon discover the first (default) user "did" 95% of the jobs. Also, totally wasted effort and bad days to boot. Time taken to set up 8 users or to turn-in to your existing Auth system vs time for every user to pick their name EVERY TIME!.Just do the right thing; it's easier.